# Laravel 8x Response download: binary files always 0 bytes

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, nginx, httpresponse

With any valid binary file (pdf, image, etc) through any route, my download is always 0 bytes. When I store the file or access it otherwise, the  file is valid.

If I run a response->download($somePath) on any valid text file (csv, json, txt), The response is valid and correct!

I've tried streamDownload(), file(), I've even tried manually sending the response without Symfony. I've tried using ob_clean(), flush(), etc. I've tried several different headers, I've tried changing the Cache-Control... nothing works.

This is on a php-fpm, with nginx, php 7.4.

```
$path = Storage::disk('test')->url('whatever.pdf');
dump(strlen(File::get($path)); // 5115
if (File::exists($path)) {
    $r = response()
        ->download(
            $path,
            'whatever.pdf',
            [
                'content-length' => strlen(File::get($path)),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'
            ]
        );
    // $r->headers->set('cache-control', 'private');

    return $r; // 0 bytes returned!

}
``
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```php
$path = Storage::disk('test')->url('whatever.pdf');
dump(strlen(File::get($path)); // 5115
if (File::exists($path)) {
    return response()->download(Storage::disk('test')->path('whatever.pdf'));
}
```

The `response()->download()` method needs an absolute path to the file which I believe the `->url()` wasn't providing.

Answer (score 0):

The request was being routed through a node micro server with the response being handled as text.

Handling the response as binary solved the issue. Previously, this server was only setup to send text.

```
res.buffer()
```